# Programmatically deleting all the code in my workbook with a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete all the code in my workbook with a macro. I'm using this code, which seems [pretty old](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=93).

```
Dim x As Integer
With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    For x = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
        .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(x)
    Next x
    For x = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
        .VBComponents(x).CodeModule.DeleteLines _
        1, .VBComponents(x).CodeModule.CountOfLines
    Next x
End With
```

I'm getting an error at `.VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(x)`, where visual basic says, "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument." According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445484(v=vs.60).aspx), this error means that either I'm using my procedure wrong, or this procedure doesn't exist anymore.

How can I fix this macro and make it work with Office 2016?

Comment: why not just save it as a .xlsx?  that removes all of the vba code from the workbook.

Comment: The error occurs when your code tries to remove the built in `Sheet` or `Workbook` modules.  The original code you linked includes `On Error Resume Next` specifically to avoid this error.

Comment: @sous2817 I think your idea is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like sous2187 said, the best method is save the file as a nonmacro file, and let excel remove the macros itself. So I did exactly that.

```
Sub delhiddensheets()

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub

Sub Valuepaste()

    Dim tabs As Object
    For Each tabs In Sheets
        With tabs
            If .Visible = True Then .Select Replace:=False
        End With
    Next tabs
    Cells.Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A20").Select

End Sub

Sub DeleteAllCode()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    newname = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)) & "_VALS.xlsx"
    ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Valuepaste
    delhiddensheets

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for an error is not due to code being old :) :P The reason is that you're deleting all modules ...including the one with the "DeleteAllModules" :P ups. 
btw just in case you need set referencest to
**Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3**
and set security to "un safe"

for details  goto 
https://www.google.pl/amp/s/christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/vba-and-git/amp/

but just for quick fix

```
Option Explicit
'@Folder("DevTools") 

Const devTools As String = "devTools" 
'This is the name of module with "RemoveAllModules" and it will be ignored

Private Sub RemoveAllModules()
Dim comp As VBComponent

 For Each comp In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
  If comp.Type = vbext_ct_ClassModule Or comp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
        If Not comp.name = devTools Then
            Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Remove comp
        End If
    End If
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Better to test for `<> vbext_ct_Document` as your code won't delete UserForms as it stands.  You also need to keep the second loop to remove code from the document modules.

Comment: The `vbext_ct_*` variables here don't have a value in my IDE (when I `Debug.Print` them I just get a blank line). Do you know how I can fix this?